# DataTable.AsEnumerable() does not Exist on my Visual Studio For Mac System.Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, system.data

I downloaded Visual Studio for Mac to give it a try.  I am working with data and linq.  When I try the following, AsEnumerable does not exist.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace TestingDataTable2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()

        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else ran into this problem with VS for Mac.  If I go into my References it is blank.  This seems like a fairly important feature to leave out, and I am wondering if this is the case, or if I did something wrong when downloading.

Edit: Error Message is - 'DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no accessible extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` package from NuGet?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/4.5.0

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy.  I kept searching DataExtensions, and it was coming up blank.